# Nexus bundle won't start after a kernel panic

Tags: jetty, nexus

I'm stuck with this error when restarting Nexus (2.11.4.01) on a RHEL 6 (openjdk 1.7) after a crash, I can't restart my nexus and I'v got no idea why there is an java.io.EOFException 
 any idea ?

```
jvm 1    | 2015-09-30 15:32:25 ERROR [WrapperListener_start_runner] *SYSTEM org.sonatype.nexus.bootstrap.jsw.JswLauncher - Failed to start
jvm 1    | java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.EOFException: input contained no data
jvm 1    |      at com.google.common.base.Throwables.propagate(Throwables.java:160) ~[na:na]
jvm 1    |      at org.sonatype.nexus.NxApplication.doStart(NxApplication.java:181) ~[na:na]
jvm 1    |      at org.sonatype.sisu.goodies.lifecycle.LifecycleSupport$Handler.doStart(LifecycleSupport.java:70) ~[na:na]
jvm 1    |      at org.sonatype.sisu.goodies.lifecycle.LifecycleHandlerContext$MainMap_Starting.started(LifecycleHandlerContext.java:255) ~[na:na]
jvm 1    |      at org.sonatype.sisu.goodies.lifecycle.LifecycleHandlerContext.started(LifecycleHandlerContext.java:57) ~[na:na]
jvm 1    |      at org.sonatype.sisu.goodies.lifecycle.LifecycleSupport.start(LifecycleSupport.java:129) ~[na:na]
jvm 1    |      at org.sonatype.nexus.webapp.WebappBootstrap.contextInitialized(WebappBootstrap.java:168) ~[na:na]
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.callContextInitialized(ContextHandler.java:782) ~[jetty-server-8.1.16.v20140903.jar:8.1.16.v20140903]
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.callContextInitialized(ServletContextHandler.java:424) ~[jetty-servlet-8.1.16.v20140903.jar:8.1.16.v20140903]
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.startContext(ContextHandler.java:774) ~[jetty-server-8.1.16.v20140903.jar:8.1.16.v20140903]
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:249) ~[jetty-servlet-8.1.16.v20140903.jar:8.1.16.v20140903]
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1242) ~[jetty-webapp-8.1.16.v20140903.jar:8.1.16.v20140903]
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:717) ~[jetty-server-8.1.16.v20140903.jar:8.1.16.v20140903]
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:494) ~[jetty-webapp-8.1.16.v20140903.jar:8.1.16.v20140903]
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64) ~[jetty-util-8.1.16.v20140903.jar:8.1.16.v20140903]
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:95) ~[jetty-server-8.1.16.v20140903.jar:8.1.16.v20140903]
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64) ~[jetty-util-8.1.16.v20140903.jar:8.1.16.v20140903]
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.doStart(HandlerCollection.java:229) ~[jetty-server-8.1.16.v20140903.jar:8.1.16.v20140903]
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64) ~[jetty-util-8.1.16.v20140903.jar:8.1.16.v20140903]
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:95) ~[jetty-server-8.1.16.v20140903.jar:8.1.16.v20140903]
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:282) ~[jetty-server-8.1.16.v20140903.jar:8.1.16.v20140903]
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64) ~[jetty-util-8.1.16.v20140903.jar:8.1.16.v20140903]
jvm 1    |      at org.sonatype.nexus.bootstrap.jetty.JettyServer$JettyMainThread.run(JettyServer.java:247) ~[nexus-bootstrap-2.11.4-01.jar:2.11.4-01]
jvm 1    | Caused by: java.io.EOFException: input contained no data
jvm 1    |      at org.codehaus.plexus.util.xml.pull.MXParser.fillBuf(MXParser.java:3005) ~[na:na]
jvm 1    |      at org.codehaus.plexus.util.xml.pull.MXParser.more(MXParser.java:3048) ~[na:na]
jvm 1    |      at org.codehaus.plexus.util.xml.pull.MXParser.parseProlog(MXParser.java:1422) ~[na:na]
jvm 1    |      at org.codehaus.plexus.util.xml.pull.MXParser.nextImpl(MXParser.java:1407) ~[na:na]
jvm 1    |      at org.codehaus.plexus.util.xml.pull.MXParser.next(MXParser.java:1105) ~[na:na]
jvm 1    |      at org.sonatype.nexus.configuration.model.io.xpp3.NexusConfigurationXpp3Reader.read(NexusConfigurationXpp3Reader.java:2458) ~[na:na]
jvm 1    |      at org.sonatype.nexus.configuration.model.io.xpp3.NexusConfigurationXpp3Reader.read(NexusConfigurationXpp3Reader.java:814) ~[na:na]
jvm 1    |      at org.sonatype.nexus.configuration.model.io.xpp3.NexusConfigurationXpp3Reader.read(NexusConfigurationXpp3Reader.java:828) ~[na:na]
jvm 1    |      at org.sonatype.nexus.configuration.source.AbstractApplicationConfigurationSource.loadConfiguration(AbstractApplicationConfigurationSource.java:99) ~[na:na]
jvm 1    |      at org.sonatype.nexus.configuration.source.FileConfigurationSource.loadConfiguration(FileConfigurationSource.java:306) ~[na:na]
jvm 1    |      at org.sonatype.nexus.configuration.source.FileConfigurationSource.loadConfiguration(FileConfigurationSource.java:156) ~[na:na]
jvm 1    |      at org.sonatype.nexus.configuration.source.FileConfigurationSource.loadConfiguration(FileConfigurationSource.java:54) ~[na:na]
jvm 1    |      at org.sonatype.nexus.configuration.application.DefaultNexusConfiguration.loadConfiguration(DefaultNexusConfiguration.java:222) ~[na:na]
jvm 1    |      at org.sonatype.nexus.NxApplication.doStart(NxApplication.java:135) ~[na:na]
jvm 1    |      ... 21 common frames omitted
wrapper  | <-- Wrapper Stopped
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The MXParser error would seem to indicate that your XML based configuration file for Nexus is blank/empty.

Comment: Yes. My nexus is failed to start and file sonatype-work/nexus/conf/nexus.xml is empty.
I delete that empty file => start success (nexus.xml is recreated) but my repositories config is lost

Comment: Yes I rebuild this file and everything is okay now, thank you , but why the hell nexus.conf go 0 byte it's strange and unsafe .

Comment: Restored nexus.xml from backup and all work perfect! Thank you guys you save my day.